# $Expand query in Odata service

Tags: asp.net, api, asp.net-web-api, odata

Usual expand query allows to expand entities to multiple level as following:

```
...A?$expand=B/C/D, G
```

But if D has also two sister entities (E and F) and I want to get them all in one query how do I get it?
[image]
So C needs to be expanded to (D, E and F) three entities.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can embed $expand in $expand. For example from [OData Spec](http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/odata/v4.0/errata02/os/complete/part1-protocol/odata-v4.0-errata02-os-part1-protocol-complete.html#_System_Query_Option_6):

http://host/service.svc/Orders?$expand=Items($expand=Product),Customer

Answer (score 0):

In OData V4, you can write that in one query like this :

```
...A?$expand=B($expand=C($expand=D, E, F)), G
```

note that you have to increase your MaxExpansionDepth in your OData controller like this :

```
[EnableQuery(MaxExpansionDepth = 3)]
```

hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

You can use '*' wiledcard.

`...A?$expand=B/C/*, G`